# Syntax error, unexpected... (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Today, after update my theme of wordpress I get an error:

> syntax error, unexpected '")) {
>   ' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

Here are lines of this function:

```
*/
if (file_exists(get_template_directory() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "." . basename(get_template_directory()) . ".php")) {
include_once get_template_directory() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "." . basename(get_template_directory()) . ".php";
```

I don't see anything wrong here. Where is the problem? Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Syntax errors are usually on a line **before** the one shown. Look at the previous lines instead.

Comment: @aynber yes it's true, that's why I copied one line before and the line with an error

Comment: One line before is a closing comment. It won't help at all.

Comment: @aynber this is the line before: if (file_exists(get_template_directory() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "." . basename(get_template_directory()) . ".php")) {

Comment: I would suggest using an IDE/Editor with syntax highlighting and error checking to really be able to see issues. Proper indentation also helps.